# Comparing Numerics in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to store non-integer numbers in my database, and be able to compare them in order to spot duplicates. Obviously, the comparison should be done to within a preset number of decimals (say, 2). So my question in a nutshell: What is the most efficient way to do this?

My first attempt was to store them as Numeric, in SQLAlchemy that would be:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    x = Column(Numeric(2, 2))
```

and then do the comparison as

```
session = Session()  # this was configured elsewhere
query = session.query(MyTable)
query = query.filter(MyTable.x == y)  # y is a float
return session.query(query.exists()).scalar()
```

Now, this failed, the condition seems to turn out false if I input y as a float.

Can I fix the above approach?
If not, what is the cleanest way to do what I want? (What is the tradeoff between fast and clean here?) Do I have to resort to converting my data to strings or integers? Or work with inequalities..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it. It seems that the numbers will be compared as strings, so I should convert my reference value to a string before comparing:

```
session = Session()  # this was configured elsewhere
query = session.query(MyTable)
query = query.filter(MyTable.x == f'{y:.2f}')  # y is a float
return session.query(query.exists()).scalar()
```

Comment: That works, but not for the reason you've thought. The string constant you pass as parameter is implicitly/automatically coerced to suitable numeric type. Read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS. Another option would be to use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) in Python to represent decimal fixed/floating point numbers; the DB-API drivers know how to convert those to suitable SQL.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä, though I don't really understand why floats are *not* automatically coerced to a 2-digit Numeric. True, I could also use Decimal; in the current case it seems to result in longer code without much benefit.

Comment: It breaks if you encounter case such as "22">"3"

Comment: True. My use case was to spot duplicates, I wanted to know whether a certain float already existed (up to two decimals), and clearly "13.32" == "13.32" should work then

Answer (score 0):

```py
from sqlalchemy import cast, Numeric
query = session.query(my_table).filter(cast(my_table.columns['col_a'], Numeric()) == 2100025895.0).count()
```

use cast function from sqlalchemy to transfer field to numeric type data

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32568008)